# Как в PyQt5 динамически изменять внутренность окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Смысл вопросо в том, что есть главное окно с много чем и например есть кнопка настройки. При нажатии на эту кнопку нужно чтобы внутренность окна поменялось на настройки. Я реализовал это тем, что у меня есть 2 окна 1 главное 2 настройки и их нужно очень много еще. При нажатии на кнопку главное окно закрывается и открывается окно настроек. Можно ли как нибудь, чтобы все поиходило в одном окне? При нажатии на кнопку менлосб все в этом окне.

Comment: Покажите пример, который у вас есть с окнами настройки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) . Содержимое у него сделай как у окон, при нажатии на кнопку настройки меняй слой стека через currentIndex